# How to assign value to multiple condition slice of an numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, variable-assignment, numpy-slicing

```
import numpy as np

minute = datetime.datetime(year,month,day,9,15,00,000000)
minute1 = minute + timedelta(minutes = 1)
main_array = np.array([[681985, minute , 2.0, 3.0], [70913, minute , 5.0, 6.0]])
temp_array = np.array([[681985, minute1 , 2.0, 3.0]])
main_array = np.concatenate((main_array, temp_array))
main_array

array([[681985, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 9, 15), 2.0, 3.0],
       [70913, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 9, 15), 5.0, 6.0],
       [681985, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 9, 16), 2.0, 3.0]],
      dtype=object)
```

> I tried assigning new value 234.7 to the slice but it does not work:

```
main_array[(main_array[:,0] == 681985) & (main_array[:,1] == minute)][0][2] = 234.7
```

Comment: Indexing with `[(main_array[:,0] == 681985) & (main_array[:,1] == minute)]`, a boolean array, creates a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `[0][2]` indexing along with boolean mask creates a copy and changes the content of the copy. In order to change the original array, you can change the indexing by moving `2` inside indexing to prevent creating a copy:

```
main_array[(main_array[:,0] == 681985) & (main_array[:,1] == minute), 2] = 234.7
```

output:

```
[[681985 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 9, 15) 234.7 3.0]
 [70913 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 9, 15) 5.0 6.0]
 [681985 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 9, 16) 2.0 3.0]]
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: @iblend171 you are welcome. Please kindly accept the answer to close the question. Thank you.